# is it possible to automatically change ownership of an account when owner is on vacation?

Tags: apex, visualforce, administration

Scenario: Account owner is going on vacation, they need to have another rep responsible for managing their account during the vacation period.
Question: is it possible to automatically assign record ownership to another user based on vacation. What are the requirements and limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be handled with a database trigger, some batch apex code, and some custom fields. Here's my vision:

1. Account custom field, type lookup(user), that stores the normal account owner.
2. User custom field, type checkbox, that indicates if they are on vacation.
3. User custom field, type lookup(user), that indicates who the temporary owner should be.
4. User trigger that invokes a batch apex class when the box toggles to checked or not checked.
5. When going from not checked to checked, assign all accounts to the temporary user and store the normal user on each account.
6. When going from checked to not checked, move them back and clear the field.

Note that this design doesn't support cascading vacations; if it would be possible for the vacation user to also go on vacation, then you would need some type of multi-layer logic, possibly using a custom object to track who is on vacation and where accounts should ultimately end up.

Comment: agreed, cascading vacationing would not be good!